# sql giving wrong result on codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

i try make a pagination on my website with codeigniter, and total_rows on this pagination is right but the result is wrong, the result just show the Sorting from the first position on the database until as much as total_rows, an example i have total_rows 3 with codition where field = TRUE but, pagination just will show 3 the most top position on database. not follow the condition where field = TRUE

I got controller like this

```
function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        // konfigurasi helper & library
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function index()
        {
            $this->model_security->getsecurity();
            $isi['content']   = 'data_pelamar/tampiltotal_dipanggil';
            $isi['judul']     = 'Data Pelamar';
            $isi['sub_judul'] = 'Total dipanggil';
            $isi['data']      = $this->db->get('data_pribadi');

            // konfigurasi class pagination
            $config['base_url']=base_url()."index.php/Total_dipanggil/index";
            $config['total_rows']= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM data_pribadi WHERE status_wawancara='sudah' and status='';")->num_rows();
            $config['per_page']= 3;
            $config['num_links'] = 2;
            $config['uri_segment']=3;

            //Tambahan untuk styling
            $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
            $config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
            $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
            $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
            $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
            $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
            $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
            $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
            $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
            $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
            $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";

            $config['first_link']='< Pertama ';
            $config['last_link']='Terakhir > ';
            $config['next_link']='> ';
            $config['prev_link']='< ';
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);


            // konfigurasi model dan view untuk menampilkan data
            $this->load->model('Model_page');
            $isi['data_dipanggil']=$this->Model_page->getAll($config);


            $this->load->view('halaman_menu',$isi);
        }
```

> and i got view like this

```
<table id="dynamic-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> No </th>
            <th> Kode Data Pribadi </th>
            <th> Nama Lengkap </th>
            <th> Jenis Kelamin </th>
            <th> Tanggal Lahir </th>
            <th> No Telepon </th>
            <th> ID </th>
            <th> Tools </th>
            <th> Status </th>
        </tr>


    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <?php 
            $no = 1;
            foreach ($data_dipanggil as $row){
            ?>
                <td> <?php echo $no++;?> </td>
                <td> <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Detail_pelamar/pindah/<?php echo $row->kode_data_pribadi ;?>"><?php echo $row->kode_data_pribadi ;?> </a>

                </td>
                <td> <?php echo $row->nama_lengkap ;?></a> </td>            
                <td> <?php echo $row->jenis_kelamin ;?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $row->tanggal_lahir ;?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $row->no_telpon ;?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $row->id ;?> </td>
                <td>

                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Total_diterima/terima_pelamar/<?php echo $row->kode_data_pribadi ;?>"  onclick="return confirm('apakah anda yakin ingin menerima data pelamar ini???') ";> 
                        Diterima
                    </a>

                    <br><br>

                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Total_ditolak/tolak_pelamar/<?php echo $row->kode_data_pribadi ;?>" onclick="return confirm('apakah anda yakin ingin menolak data pelamar ini???') ";>
                        Ditolak
                    </a> 

                    <br><br>

                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Total_pelamar/delete/<?php echo $row->kode_data_pribadi; ?>" onclick="return confirm('apakah anda yakin ingin menghapus data ini???'); ">
                        Hapus Data
                    </a>

                </td>

                <td>

                    Sudah Dipanggil

                </td>
        </tr>    

        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `data_pribadi` WHERE status_wawancara = 'sudah' && status = '';"; 
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            $result = $query->row_array();
            $count = $result['COUNT(*)'];

            if($count < 1){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="9" align="center">
                        Data Tidak ada!
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php }
        }
        ?>

    </tbody>

    <?php
        echo $this->pagination->create_links();
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this line

```
$isi['data_dipanggil']=$this->Model_page->getAll($config);
```

change to this

```
$isi['data_dipanggil']=$this->Model_page->getAll($config['per_page']);
```

then in model where you are writing getall() method pass any variable like

```
public getall($pagination)
{
// query
//use limit condition
$this->db->limit($pagination)
}
```